# How Do I Add a Conditional Statement to Check for Post Type Taxonomy in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement, conditional-statements, custom-taxonomy

I currently have the following Conditional Statement going -

```
<?php if ( is_front_page() || is_page_template( 'page-fullwidth.php' ) || is_product() ) { ?>

<?php } elseif ( is_product_category( array( 'engagement-rings', 'artcarved', 'demarco', 'gabriel-co', 'ajaffe', 'ritani-rings', 'askher', 'verragio-gallery', 'scott-kay-gallery', 'tacori-gallery', 'martin-flyer-gallery', 'henri-daussi-gallery', 'bez-ambar-gallery', 'art-carved-gallery', 'michael-m-ring-designer-gallery', 'womens-wedding-bands', 'designer-engagement-rings' ) ) ) { ?>
<div id="side-nav" class="three columns">
<?php if (!function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar('Engagement Ring Sidebar')) : ?><?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

My problem lies in adding to my elseif an "OR Statement" to test if it's a Custom Post Type of 'PRODUCT' with the Custom Taxonomy of 'Diamond-Cut' or 'Ring-Style'.

Each custom taxonomy also has sub-taxonomies under it as well

Currently the statement works fine - but I want to be able to include those search results pages into my conditional statement so the proper content is displayed.

I'm not sure if this tidbit will help - but this is what is after my domain in the address bar when the page is displayed - '?post_type=product&diamond-cut=round'

I'd like every 'Diamond-Cut' and every 'Ring-Style' to be included in my elseif.

I've tried is_tax('diamond-cut') and it doesn't work.

Comment: What is the function `is_product()`?  Is this a custom function you wrote, or the WooCommerce function?

Comment: is `diamond-cut` a subtaxonomy of something else

Comment: is_product() is a post-type created by WooCommerce

Comment: diamond-cut is a main taxonomy - ROUND is a sub-taxonomy of diamond-cut